# How to assign a value to Form field from association form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, designer-workflow

In Sharepoint 2010 Workflow, there is an Association form with two fields.
When associating the workflow with the list, the user is populating the association fields.

Now, I would like to assign the association fields to the fields in the form.

How can I assign values to list form fields from association form fields?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Now, I would like to assign the association fields to the fields in the form" which form are you referencing to.

Comment: There is only 1 form with a custom list.

Comment: There is only 1 form with a custom list. and it has a workflow. workflow contains a association fields.  when user fills the form, some fields shall be automatically filled by assigning values from association form